# OnClientClick does not works on asp.net LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, linkbutton, onclientclick

I have an asp.net `linkbutton`, which contains the `OnClientClick` property, however the function within the `OnClientClick` never gets called, it directly jumps to `OnClick` function.
Below are the 2 ways I am using LinkButton as:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CssClass="button" Text="Browse Thumbnail" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this slide?');" 
     CommandName="DeleteThumbnail" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'>
   <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/images/delete.gif" ID="imgDelete" runat="server"></asp:Image>  
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Both of the approaches does not works.

Can anyone please provide some solution for the same.

Comment: you havnt defined OnClick in both of those approaches, so he can't jump into OnClick

Comment: you are missing a `JavaScript` call you should try something like this 
`onclick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this slide?')"`

Comment: I mean it just postbacks without firing OnClientClick Event

Comment: Below? can you please let me know how? i have double quotes outside and single inside

Comment: Content should be double quote and parameter should be single.Just posted my answer below.Try and let me know.

Comment: There is nothing essentially wrong with the declaration of the script - just tried it as is and it worked, so problem seems to be elsewhere. Are you sure you are not overriding this handler? Maybe in codebehind settings `Attributes["onclick"]`, or in javascript?

Comment: No i haven't declared any attributes anywhere from the code behind

Comment: @Abbas you not getting confirm window?

Comment: no, it seems like the issue is in IE only, in FF (2nd approach) is working fine. 1st still have issues in all browsers

Comment: Can you post the HTML into that both link buttons are rendered?

Comment: You guys can see the page in action: http://kb.dev.asentechdev1.com/slideshowadmin_v2.aspx, site requires credentials here are they: username - Developer (Only for IE its .\Developer) and password: plmnko-09, click on the Browse Thumbnail Button, it will just postbacks, its a linkbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is most probably some other page element that is preventing this event from being fired.

Do you have any other page elements that might interfere? Have you tried removing all other page elements but this one? Do you have some AJAX calls that might interfere? Have you tried this with a simple html element (not asp.net)?

You are most probably doing everything fine in your link button but it seems like problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes you were right, problem was elsewhere, i was having a function which was preventing anchor tag's onclick event.

Answer (score 3):

```
  OnClientClick="javascript:return confirmAction();"  

  function confirmAction() {  
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {  
        // you clicked the OK button.  
        // you can allow the form to post the data.  
        return true;  
    }  
    else {  
        return false;  
        }  
    }
```

implement the Onclick on the server side

```
 protected void lnkdelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
 {  
 }
```

and if you dnt want to call server method use this

```
   OnClientClick="javascript:confirmAction(); return false;"
```

Comment: I tried this
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CssClass="button" Text="Browse Thumbnail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('Are you sure');"></asp:LinkButton>
Still that too not working

Comment: make function as above and try

Comment: No its not working i made below function:
 function Navigate() {
                    javascript: window.open("http://www.microsoft.com");
                }
and OnClientClick="javascript:Navigate()" but its not working

Comment: OnClientClick="javascript:Navigate();

Comment: I also tried calling the OnClientClick from Page_Load:
btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?')"
and
btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:Navigate();"
both does not works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29169/discussion-between-abbas-and-shafqat-masood)

Answer (score 0):

Place it in single quotes like below,

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn" CssClass="button" Text="Browse Thumbnail" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 function Navigate() 
 { 
     javascript: window.open("microsoft.com"); 
     return false;
 }
```

and on clientclick as follows

```
OnClientClick="return javascript:Navigate()"
```

or even

```
 function Navigate() 
 { 
     window.open("microsoft.com"); 
     return false;
 }

 OnClientClick="return Navigate()"
```

Comment: it will work. Have you checked for `js` `javascript` error on the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your `OnClientClick` method it should prompt confirm window. but you haven't specify the onclick event of the link button. So you will not able to get the event from code behind.

You may need to enable java scripts for your browser

[How to enable JavaScript in a web browser?](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/howtoscript)

Are you using Ajax toolkit? Update panel? then you need to register script by using script manager

To inject a confirm script from a AJAX postback,

```
ScriptManager.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(btn, Page.GetType(), "confirm", "return confirm('Are you sure');");
```

Comment: Javascript is enabled, i am getting confirm box on HTML input button, but its not working in asp:linkbutton

Comment: is this 
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" runat="server" Text="SOMETHING" OnClientClick="return confirm('are you sure?');"></asp:LinkButton>
working?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have Disabled the javascript in IE. Just enable it & you are good to go. You can follow this post to enable/disable the javascript in IE:

http://browsers.about.com/od/internetexplorertutorials/ss/disable-javascript-ie9.htm