# asp.net custom button OnClientClick not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an issue with a custom button i created for the purpose of using text and html between tags. everything works properly except for OnClientClick event.

Here is the Button class in its own project.

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class BButton : Button
{
    protected override string TagName
    {
        get { return "button"; }
    }
    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.Button; }
    }
    public new string Text
    {
        get { return ViewState["NewText"] as string; }
        set { ViewState["NewText"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value); }
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(this.Text);
        Controls.Add(lc);
        base.Text = UniqueID;
    }
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [DisplayName("GlyphIcon")]
    public string GlyphIcon
    {
        get { return this.ViewState["GlyphIcon"] as string; }
        set { this.ViewState["GlyphIcon"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value); }
    }
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [DisplayName("FontAwsome")]
    public string FontAwsome
    {
        get { return this.ViewState["FontAwsome"] as string; }
        set { this.ViewState["FontAwsome"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(value); }
    }
    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GlyphIcon))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "glyphicon " + this.GlyphIcon);
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginRight, "5px");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.RenderEndTag(); // </span>
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FontAwsome))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "fa fa " + this.FontAwsome);
            writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginRight, "5px");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.RenderEndTag(); // </span>
        }
        RenderChildren(writer);
    }
}
```

And this is the asp page call that works:.

```
<CPCC:BButton ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Delete this item?');"><i class="fa fa-trash-o">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;<asp:Localize runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnDeleteText" />
</CPCC:StyleButton>
```

This call will not work:

```
<CPCC:BButton id="btnAdd" CssClass="btn btn-success" runat="server" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" ValidationGroup="Create" OnClientClick="ShowProgressDialog('Creating Account...');"> <i class="fa fa-plus">&nbsp;</i>&nbsp;<asp:Localize runat="server" meta:resourcekey="btnCreateText"/> </CPCC:StyleButton>
```

Everything works except for `OnClientClick="return confirm('Creating Account...');"`on buttons that require validation, and this works properly with asp:button. Am i missing something here?

Comment: can you try using JavaScript - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16293456/onclientclick-does-not-works-on-asp-net-linkbutton

Answer (score 0):

In `BButton`, you have overridden the `RenderContents` method of the ASP:Button control, so the base method (which would normally render the Javascript) is getting skipped.

You need to add code to your `RenderContents` method that reads the OnClientClick property and outputs appropriate markup.

Or, if you're very clever, maybe you can find a way to do it by calling `base.RenderContents()`.

Or maybe you just need the child control (the literal) to respond to clicks, in which case you could try

```
protected override void OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreRender(e);

    LiteralControl lc = new LiteralControl(this.Text);
    lc.Attributes.Add("onclick",this.OnClientClick);
    Controls.Add(lc);
    base.Text = UniqueID;
}
```

Comment: Tracing this further i found that it does works on cancel buttons where CausesValidation="False" but does not work when validation is required. I am editing my post now to reflect the change.